# How to get a Waddington landscape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The idea is to make a plot like this

[image]
Source: http://figshare.com/articles/_Waddington_s_8220_Epigenetic_Landscape_8221_/620879

But only with 2 wells in the front, not 4. Also the colors don't matter.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-6:40,domain y=0:12,view={-80}{40},colormap/blackwhite, width=\textwidth]
\addplot3[surf,shader=faceted interp]({x},{y},{exp(-0.07*x)*cos(deg(y)) + (exp((0.15*x)-6.5) * (1+cos(deg(y)/2)))});
\fill[ball color=orange] (axis cs:30,6,0.5) circle [radius=0.2cm];
% 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

As you can see. I am very close. Thanks a lot to @percusse for the initial help !

However, few small things remain, eg

- the sides could be more round like in the schematic
- instead of having the "big" mountain be concave, it should be convex, eg "bloated"
- the back curve could be a bit more steep

The idea in the code is to have a parametric curve in the front defined by `exp(-0.07*x)*cos(deg(y))` and a second parametric curve having more weight in the back `(exp((0.15*x)-6.5) * (1+cos(deg(y)/2)))`

Any pointers on how to get the last 20% done would be appreciated :)

**Edit 11.06.2014**

Here is an update using @TonioElGringo comment below.

[image]

produced by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,domain y=0:1,view={-10}{50},colormap/jet, width=\textwidth]
\addplot3[surf,shader=faceted interp]({x},{y},{1-((1-y)*(exp(-80*(x-1/3)^2)+exp(-80*(x-2/3)^2))/2 + y*exp(-60*(x-1/2)^2)/5)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Small Edit**

I just attach a version with 50 samples, to show how it looks when it is more "smooth".

I just added `, samples=50` to the addplot options. Careful, this might need you to tweak with the memory settings of tex because of many calculations to be done.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this is a tex-related question. You are looking for a better suited function. Try 1-[(1-y)*(exp(-80*(x-1/3)^2)+exp(-80*(x-2/3)^2))/2 + y*exp(-60*(x-1/2)^2)/5] (with x and y between 0 and 1)

Comment: @TonioElGringo I'll check and post updates. It looks promising though from first glance at Wolfram. Can you let us know how you come up with more complex formulae like this?

Comment: I simply used a linear interpolation between a couple of gaussian at y=0 and another smaller gaussian at y=1. The shape of the gaussian function is flatter on the sides than the cosine. You can tweak the function I gave you to adjust the position (1/3, 2/3 and 1/2) of the gaussians, their height (1/2 and 1/5), and their sharpness (80 and 60).

Comment: @TonioElGringo While the plot can still be optimized, I think you answered all my remaining questions. This is exactly what such a plot should look like! If you want, you can just copy paste my edit, make it answer, and then we can close the question!

Comment: Is it necessary to be written in TikZ or is something like Asymptote (which I think is more appropiate) acceptable?

Comment: @Manuel frankly it doesn't matter. If anything, this example could be a good training for people out there so if we showcase different solutions, that would ideal! As long as it produces a PDF that can be imported somewhere else, it's OK for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a different type of function, like the following one:

```
f(x,y) = 1 - [(1-y)*(exp(-a1*(x-1/3)^2)+exp(-a1*(x-2/3)^2)) * l1 
             +   y *(exp(-a2*(x-1/2)^2)) * l2]
```

This function is simply a linear interpolation between a couple of gaussian at `y=0` and another gaussian at `y=1`. The parameters *a1*,*a2*,*l1* and *l2* allow you to change the size of the gaussians.

Using the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,domain y=0:1,view={-10}{50},colormap/jet, width=\textwidth]
\addplot3[surf,shader=faceted interp, samples=50]({x},{y},{1-((1-y)*(exp(-80*(x-1/3)^2)+exp(-80*(x-2/3)^2))/2 + y*exp(-60*(x-1/2)^2)/5)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

We get

[image: Resulting surface]